# print numpy str representation 2 n decimal places

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6

I have a small script that works fine except for the fact that I want to control how many decimal places the output displays.

I thought I found what I need:

[https://markhneedham.com/blog/2017/11/19/python-3-typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-numpy-ndarray-**format**/](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2017/11/19/python-3-typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-numpy-ndarray-__format__/)

As well as a few other similar posts on Stackoverflow.

My code runs without error, but both of the print statements generate the exact same output.

What is the correct way to limit the output to n decimal places? (I am wanting 2 in this example).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
# from timeit import Timer


file = 'd:\\python\\codebasics\\machine_learning\\homeprices.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df)
print()
plt.xlabel('area(sqr ft)')
plt.ylabel('price(US$)')
plt.scatter(df.area, df.price, color='red', marker='+')
plt.show()

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['area']], df.price)

print(reg.predict(3300))
print("{:2}".format(str(np.array(reg.predict(3300)))))



[628715.75342466]
[628715.75342466]
```

Comment: Maybe `print ("{:.2f}".format(float(reg.predict(3300))))`?

Comment: Bingo!  That was it.  float(np.array(reg ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"{:2}"` with `"{:.2f}"` does what you want. `f` means that it's float while `.2` means two decimals.

Comment: I get this when I apply your change:  ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'